# Fill between curves in pgfplots for two plots side-by-side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

In the following code I want to have the area between the curves filled in both plots. I tried the "fill between" package but when I apply it to both plots, the first one is not displayed.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Anders

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
name=plotA,
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-1,
xmax=2,
ymin=-2,
ymax=2
]

\addplot[line width=2pt,name path=A1] coordinates {(0,2)  (0.5,-1) (1,3) };

\addplot[name path=B1,orange,mark=*,line width=2pt] coordinates  {(0,0) (1,1)};

\addplot[gray!30] fill between[of=A1 and B1];

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
name=plotB,
at={($(plotA.south east)+(2cm,0)$)},
anchor=south west,
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-1,
xmax=2,
ymin=-2,
ymax=2
]

\addplot[line width=2pt,name path=A2] coordinates {(0,2)  (0.5,-1) (1,3) };

\addplot[name path=B2,blue,mark=*,line width=2pt] coordinates  {(0,0) (1,1)};
\addplot[gray!30] fill between[of=A2 and B2];

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I get a graphic, but I don't know if is plotA or plotB (maybe is plot B) ¿are not the same?. Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` before `\begin{document}`. Sorry for my English.

Comment: The graphics are superimposed. Try, in plotA, making (2,2) in path B1 to see that. Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` before `\begin{document}`. Sorry for my English.

Comment: But if I remove the \addplot fill between then the plots are not superimposed anymore.

Comment: This is a bug and has been reported already to the bug tracker as [bug 122](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/122/). I have edited the bug because up to now it was thought that it shows up in combination with the `groupplots` library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be solved by updating PGFPlots.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of PGFPlots v1.14 the bug reported in [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299847/fill-between-curves-in-pgfplots-for-two-plots-side-by-side#comment725977_299847) has been fixed and now gives the desired result.

[image: image showing the result of the code of the question]